# Python convert DOCX to PDF after modifying document and export PDF to download (DJANGO)

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that reads a document template (DOCX) and modifies it. The program is working well, but it is returning to download a DOCX document (as expected). So, I want to edit the download file format to PDF. I thought of converting the DOCX file to PDF but I couldn't find a working way to do that.

My actual code looks like this:

```
    f = io.BytesIO()
    document.write(f)
    length = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)

    response = HttpResponse(
        f.getvalue(),
        content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    )

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + formular.name + '.docx'
    response['Content-Length'] = length
    return response
```

I want to find a working method of converting the DOCX file f to a PDF file before returning that as response.

Comment: convert docx to pdf in python: https://michalzalecki.com/converting-docx-to-pdf-using-python/

Answer (score 0):

you need pywin32 library for that purpose. which you can use like so

```
   def convert_to_pdf(doc):
      try:
       word = client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
      new_name = doc.replace(".docx", r".pdf")
      worddoc = word.Documents.Open(doc)
      worddoc.SaveAs(new_name, FileFormat = 17)
      worddoc.Close()
     except Exception, e:
        return e
     finally:
        word.Quit()
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that Word must be installed to make that work.